# Select Join optimization in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

How can I optimize this select-join statement? In SQLITE.

```
SELECT main.theme.code AS theme_code
    ,main.genre.name AS genre_name
    ,main.artist.name AS artist_name
    ,main.theme.name AS theme_name
    ,main.theme.path AS theme_path
    ,main.genre.genre_index AS genre_index
    ,main.theme.theme_index AS theme_index
    ,main.artist.artist_index AS artist_index
FROM main.genre
    INNER JOIN main.artist ON main.artist.genre_index = main.genre.genre_index
    INNER JOIN main.theme ON main.theme.artist_index = main.artist.artist_index
WHERE main.theme.theme_index BETWEEN 143 AND 167
ORDER BY main.theme.theme_index ASCv
```

Comment: Basically, you can be sure you have indexes on the `join` keys -- but they are probably already primary keys.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, yes, all primary keys.

Comment: Table and index definitions, and [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output would be useful. And run a [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) if you haven't already, to give the optimizer real numbers to work with.